# ¿Cómo soluciono el error de "No module named 'wxPython'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxwidgets

He instalado el wxPython, la versión 4.0.0b2, mediante *pip* en Windows:

> pip install -U wxPython

y al intentar importar me sale el error:

> ImportError No module named 'wxPython'.

Aquí comparto el código. Es sobre un graficador de funciones. Me gustaría saber, por qué me sale error, si ya tengo instalado ese módulo.

```
import wxPython
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import sin,cos,tan,log,sqrt,exp,linspace

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title)
        self.pcanvas = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.pctrls = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        # Sizers
        self.szmain = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1)
        self.szcanvas = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.szctrls = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=5, hgap=5)

        self.initCanvas()
        self.initCtrls()
        self.initMenu()

        self.pcanvas.SetSizer(self.szcanvas)
        self.pctrls.SetSizer(self.szctrls)

        self.szmain.Add(self.pcanvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szmain.Add(self.pctrls, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.szmain)

        self.intervalo = [0.0,10.0]
        self.xlabel = "x"
        self.ylabel = "y"
        self.Fit()
        self.Centre(True)

    def initCanvas(self):
        # Creamos Figure
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        # FigureCanvas
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.pcanvas, -1, self.figure)

        self.szcanvas.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)


    def initCtrls(self):
        colores = "rojo verde azul negro amarillo".split()
        estilos = "- -- -.".split()
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.pctrls, -1, " f(x) ", size=(40, 25))
        self.fun = wx.TextCtrl(self.pctrls, -1)
        self.bot = wx.Button(self.pctrls, -1, "Graficar", size=(80, 25))
        self.color = wx.ComboBox(self.pctrls, -1, choices = colores, value='Color', size=(80,-1))
        self.estilo = wx.ComboBox(self.pctrls, -1, choices = estilos, value='Estilo', size=(80,-1))

        # Fuente
        mod_font = self.label.GetFont()
        mod_font.SetPointSize(12)
        mod_font.SetWeight(wx.BOLD)
        self.label.SetFont(mod_font)
        self.fun.SetFont(mod_font)
        self.fun.SetForegroundColour((100,100,255))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.graficar, self.bot)

        self.szctrls.Add(self.label, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.fun, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.color, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.estilo, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.bot, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.AddGrowableCol(1) # "Expandir" el TextCtrl 

    def initMenu(self):
        m_archivo = wx.Menu()
        guardar = m_archivo.Append(-1, "Guardar")
        salir = m_archivo.Append(-1, "Salir")

        m_configurar = wx.Menu()
        intervalo = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Modificar intervalo")
        xlabel = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Etiqueta eje X") 
        ylabel = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Etiqueta eje Y")

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.Append(m_archivo, "Archivo")
        menu_bar.Append(m_configurar, "Configurar")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.guardar, guardar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.salir, salir)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_intervalo, intervalo)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_xlabel, xlabel)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_ylabel, ylabel)

    def graficar(self,event):
        # Equivalencia de colores 
        list_color = {'rojo': (1,0,0),
        'verde': (0,1,0),
        'azul': (0,0,1),
        'negro': (0,0,0),
        'amarillo': (1,1,0)}
        f = self.fun.GetValue() # f(x)
        estilo = self.estilo.GetValue() 
        color = self.color.GetValue()
        if estilo == 'Estilo':
            estilo = '-' # Linea continua por default
        if color == 'Color':
            color = 'negro' # Color negro default
        color = list_color.get(color)
        x = linspace(self.intervalo[0], self.intervalo[1])
        try:
            y = eval(f)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox(u'Inserte una función f(x)','msg')
            return # go out

        self.axes.cla() # Limpiar axes 
        hLine = self.axes.plot(x, y, lw = 2, linestyle=estilo, color=color) # Gráfica
        self.axes.set_title('f(x) = ' + f) # Configurar título de la gráfica
        self.axes.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        self.axes.grid(True) # Coloca rejilla
        self.canvas.draw() # Redibuja el elementos "canvas"

    def guardar(self,event):
        wldc = "PNG (*.png)|*.png"
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self, "Guardar", os.getcwd(), style=wx.SAVE, wildcard=wldc)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.figure.savefig(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()

    def salir(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def mod_intervalo(self,event):
        message = "Inserte los extremos del intervalos separados por una coma."
        caption = "Intervalo"
        default = "0,10"
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            intervalo = dlg.GetValue()
        self.intervalo = [float(x) for x in intervalo.split(",")]

    def mod_xlabel(self,event):
        message = "Inserte una nueva etiqueta"
        caption = "Etiqueta eje X"
        default = "x" 
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.xlabel = dlg.GetValue()
        self.axes.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def mod_ylabel(self,event):
        message = "Inserte una nueva etiqueta"
        caption = "Etiqueta eje Y"
        default = "y"
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.ylabel = dlg.GetValue()
        self.axes.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None,"Graficador")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

**Edición:**

Al final he conseguido importar correctamente el módulo, pero ahora me sale el siguiente error:

```
Excepción "TypeError"
FlexGridSizer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: 'rows' is not a valid keyword argument
  overload 2: 'rows' is not a valid keyword argument
  overload 3: not enough arguments
  overload 4: not enough arguments
```

Comment: El problema lo tienes en un ordenador con Linux o Windows... es importante saberlo para resolver el problema de localización y ajuste de las librerias ...

Comment: Es en Windows @luisgulo

Comment: El import es `import wx` no `import wxPython`, si no me equivoco.

Comment: También probé con import wx y me sale error igual. De hecho en mi pregunta iba a colocar primero con el wx, se me fue el "lapsus dedus" :)

Comment: instalaste con `pip`? Estás usando python2.7?

Comment: Instalé con pip y uso Python 3 @amenadiel

Comment: Si estás seguro de que tu `pip` está instalando paquetes para python3, entonces podrías probar `pip install wx`. Pero pensaba que `wxPython` sólo corría en Python2 a menos que usaras el release `wxPython_Phoenix`.

Comment: Esta fue la forma en que instale ex wxpython: pip install -U wxPython

Comment: Vete a la terminal y mira a ver si tienes de verdad wxPython instalado en Python 3 con `py -3 -m pip list`. Si no aparece en la lista instala con `py -3 -m pip install wxPython`. Si se instalo correctamente pero no puedes importar posiblemente el directorio donde se instala no esta en el PYTHONPATH.

Comment: te refieres al Path de las variables de entorno? @FJSevilla

Comment: No, son los directorios donde Python busca los paquetes cuando se importa un módulo (además del directorio actual). No obstante no debieras tener este problema. ¿Has comprobado lo que te comento antes?  Si después de `py -3 -m pip install wxpython` (asegúrate que termina sin excepciones) haces `py -3` en la misma terminal y luego `import wx` ¿obtienes el mismo error?

Comment: Hice todo tal cual me dijiste, en la consola o cmd, no me sale error cuando doy import wx. Pero luego cuando corro el archivo arriba descrito, me vuelve a salir error, tanto si dejo wxpython o coloco wx:   File "C:\Users\MONITO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DRa0.436\MiniGraficador.py", line 5, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named 'wx'

Comment: Pues la única explicación es que no estas usando el mismo intérprete en el que instalas wxpython para ejecutar el script  . Si el import te funciona la instalación es correcta. ¿Tienes varios intérpretes instalados? ¿Python 3 y 2 en el mismo sistema? ¿Usas un entornos virtuales? ¿Usas un IDE? ¿Que versión del intérprete se ejecuta si en la CMD  escribes simplemente  `py`?

Comment: Hola, ya pudehacer todo de nuevo en mi laptop, y si funciona el wx. Pero ahora el codigo me arroja error respecto al 'wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1)' supuestamente los argumentos son incorrectos.

Comment: El problema se debe a que el código no está actualizado para usar wxPython-Phoenix. He creado una respuesta agrupando lo que hemos ido comentando sobre el error de importación y he añadido la solución a este nuevo error. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque el paquete se identifique como `wxpython` en PyPI, a la hora de importar la forma correcta es:

```
import wx
```

Cuando instales vía PIP es recomendable usarlo como módulo y hacer explícita la versión de Python en la que quieres hacer la instalación. En Windows con versiones recientes de Python 3 puedes hacer uso de Python Launcher. Por ejemplo para instalar wxPython en Python 3.6 puedes hacer:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install wxpython
```

Luego recuerda lanzar el script con el intérprete adecuado:

```
py -3.6 MiniGrafi‌​cador.py
```

Si sigues con problemas al importar y la instalación se completó sin errores, el problema puede estar en que el directorio de instalación del paquete no esté en el PYTHONPATH por alguna razón (cosa que en principio no debería pasar). Si instalas el paquete de forma local (`-U`/`--user`), en Windows se debería instalar en `%APPDATA%\Python`. Si usas un entorno virtual debes instalar el paquete en él o en todo caso permitir el acceso a los paquetes del sistema.

Por último, tu código es para versiones anteriores de wxPhython y no va a funcionar en wxPython-Phoenix. Hay dos cosas a cambiar:

- Tienes dos instancias de [`wx.FlexGridSizer`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FlexGridSizer.html#wx.FlexGridSizer.__init__) que no reciben los parámetros correctos para el inicializador.

  Debes cambiar estas dos líneas:

  ```
  self.szmain = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1)
  self.szctrls = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=5, hgap=5)
  ```

  Por alguna de las implementaciones válidas (puedes verlas en el enlace a la documentación que dejo arriba), por ejemplo:

  ```
  self.szmain = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1, vgap = 0, hgap = 0)
  self.szctrls = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=5, vgap = 0, hgap=5)
  ```
- En el `FileDialog` usado para guardar la gráfica, debes cambiar `wx.SAVE` por [`wx.FD_SAVE`](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.FileDialog.html#styles-window-styles). Quedando por tanto:

  ```
  dlg=wx.FileDialog(self, "Guardar", os.getcwd(), style=wx.FD_SAVE,
                    wildcard=wldc)
  ```

El código puede quedar por tanto de la siguiente forma:

```
import wx
import os
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from numpy import sin,cos,tan,log,sqrt,exp,linspace

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title)
        self.pcanvas = wx.Panel(self,-1)
        self.pctrls = wx.Panel(self,-1)

        # Sizers
        self.szmain = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=2, cols=1, vgap = 0, hgap = 0)
        self.szcanvas = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.szctrls = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=5, vgap = 0, hgap=5)

        self.initCanvas()
        self.initCtrls()
        self.initMenu()

        self.pcanvas.SetSizer(self.szcanvas)
        self.pctrls.SetSizer(self.szctrls)

        self.szmain.Add(self.pcanvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szmain.Add(self.pctrls, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.szmain)

        self.intervalo = [0.0,10.0]
        self.xlabel = "x"
        self.ylabel = "y"
        self.Fit()
        self.Centre(True)

    def initCanvas(self):
        # Creamos Figure
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        # FigureCanvas
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.pcanvas, -1, self.figure)

        self.szcanvas.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)


    def initCtrls(self):
        colores = "rojo verde azul negro amarillo".split()
        estilos = "- -- -.".split()
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self.pctrls, -1, " f(x) ", size=(40, 25))
        self.fun = wx.TextCtrl(self.pctrls, -1)
        self.bot = wx.Button(self.pctrls, -1, "Graficar", size=(80, 25))
        self.color = wx.ComboBox(self.pctrls, -1, choices = colores, value='Color', size=(80,-1))
        self.estilo = wx.ComboBox(self.pctrls, -1, choices = estilos, value='Estilo', size=(80,-1))

        # Fuente
        mod_font = self.label.GetFont()
        mod_font.SetPointSize(12)
        mod_font.SetWeight(wx.BOLD)
        self.label.SetFont(mod_font)
        self.fun.SetFont(mod_font)
        self.fun.SetForegroundColour((100,100,255))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.graficar, self.bot)

        self.szctrls.Add(self.label, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.fun, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.color, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.estilo, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.Add(self.bot, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.szctrls.AddGrowableCol(1) # "Expandir" el TextCtrl 

    def initMenu(self):
        m_archivo = wx.Menu()
        guardar = m_archivo.Append(-1, "Guardar")
        salir = m_archivo.Append(-1, "Salir")

        m_configurar = wx.Menu()
        intervalo = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Modificar intervalo")
        xlabel = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Etiqueta eje X") 
        ylabel = m_configurar.Append(-1, "Etiqueta eje Y")

        menu_bar = wx.MenuBar()
        menu_bar.Append(m_archivo, "Archivo")
        menu_bar.Append(m_configurar, "Configurar")
        self.SetMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.guardar, guardar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.salir, salir)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_intervalo, intervalo)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_xlabel, xlabel)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.mod_ylabel, ylabel)

    def graficar(self,event):
        # Equivalencia de colores 
        list_color = {'rojo': (1,0,0),
        'verde': (0,1,0),
        'azul': (0,0,1),
        'negro': (0,0,0),
        'amarillo': (1,1,0)}
        f = self.fun.GetValue() # f(x)
        estilo = self.estilo.GetValue() 
        color = self.color.GetValue()
        if estilo == 'Estilo':
            estilo = '-' # Linea continua por default
        if color == 'Color':
            color = 'negro' # Color negro default
        color = list_color.get(color)
        x = linspace(self.intervalo[0], self.intervalo[1])
        try:
            y = eval(f)
        except:
            wx.MessageBox(u'Inserte una función f(x)','msg')
            return # go out

        self.axes.cla() # Limpiar axes 
        hLine = self.axes.plot(x, y, lw = 2, linestyle=estilo, color=color) # Gráfica
        self.axes.set_title('f(x) = ' + f) # Configurar título de la gráfica
        self.axes.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        self.axes.grid(True) # Coloca rejilla
        self.canvas.draw() # Redibuja el elementos "canvas"

    def guardar(self,event):
        wldc = "PNG (*.png)|*.png"
        dlg=wx.FileDialog(self, "Guardar", os.getcwd(), style=wx.FD_SAVE, wildcard=wldc)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.figure.savefig(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()

    def salir(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def mod_intervalo(self,event):
        message = "Inserte los extremos del intervalos separados por una coma."
        caption = "Intervalo"
        default = "0,10"
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            intervalo = dlg.GetValue()
        self.intervalo = [float(x) for x in intervalo.split(",")]

    def mod_xlabel(self,event):
        message = "Inserte una nueva etiqueta"
        caption = "Etiqueta eje X"
        default = "x" 
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.xlabel = dlg.GetValue()
        self.axes.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def mod_ylabel(self,event):
        message = "Inserte una nueva etiqueta"
        caption = "Etiqueta eje Y"
        default = "y"
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message, caption, default)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.ylabel = dlg.GetValue()
        self.axes.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None,"Graficador")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu gran ayuda como siempre! Tu si Ah! Fue muy valiosa tu respuesta! Muchisimas Gracias!